# How do I programmatically populate a field if another one is empty?

Tags: 7, feeds

I have a CSV feed running and it currently works perfectly. The client now wants to populate a certain field with a sub-string of another field if the first field is empty, on import. I can't see a way to do that with the normal feeds field mapping or tamper.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom module, in **mymodule.module** use [hook_node_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x)

```
function mymodule_node_update($node) {

  if (!isset($node->field_example[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) { 
  // If field example is not set (is empty), then...

     $new_value = // ...do some stuff to compute a new value for the field.
     $node->field_example2[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $new_value;
     field_attach_update('node', $node);

  }

}
```